# Cannot sort date ascending python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with dates from 2019/1/1 to 2019/12/31

The date is in object type so I converted to datetime:

`df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

After that I want to sort the date ascending using:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].sort_values()
```

However I failed and the date stills start from 2019/01/06 with +7 Days interval:

- 2019/01/06
- 2019/01/13
- 2019/01/20
- 2019/01/27
- 2019/02/03
  ....
  and so on

I dont know what i'm doing wrong. Please support

Comment: df.date.sort_values(ascending=False)?

Comment: Ummm... that is sorted ascending.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.